# Как запустить веб-сервис?

Tags: веб-служба, glassfish, java, linux

Руководство поставило задачу: Написать веб-сервис, который будет самопроизвольно запускаться по заданному алгоритму(например каждый четверг в 3 часа ночи). Собственно вопрос реально ли это(что то мне кажется, что нет)? 
Среда работы Glassfish server установленный на Red Hat Linux.

Comment: на всяк случай crontab:

     0 4 * * 4 curl http://localhost/app 

ну и хорошо бы уточнить смысл фразы "самопроизвольно запускаться"

Comment: нужен сервис который будет через определенные интервалы времени(или в конкретное заданное время) запускаться и отрабатывать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://quartz-scheduler.org/

> Quartz is a richly featured, open source job scheduling library that can be integrated within virtually any Java application - from the smallest stand-alone application to the largest e-commerce system. Quartz can be used to create simple or complex schedules for executing tens, hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands of jobs; jobs whose tasks are defined as standard Java components that may execute virtually anything you may program them to do. The Quartz Scheduler includes many enterprise-class features, such as support for JTA transactions and clustering.